# Gray out disabled button

Tags: android, android-theme, floating-action-button, material-components-android

I'm currently writing my first Android application. so far, I've added the basic layout as well as a floating action button.

To disable the button, I am using `FloatingActionButton#setEnabled(false)`. However, I don't like that there's no visual indication whether the button is disabled. I think it would be nice for the user to actually know if the button can be pressed at this moment.

I tried replacing the `backgroundTint` of the button with a selector, however that does not work:

`res/layout/activity_detail.xml`:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
  android:id="@+id/fab_next"
  android:backgroundTint="@drawable/disableable_button" />
```

`res/drawable/disableable_button`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@color/gray_500"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@color/purple_700"/>
</selector>
```

I also read that Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored can be used to colorize disable buttons, but I couldn't get it to work either.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When the `FloatingActionButton` is disabled state the color is based on the `colorOnSurface`.

You can customize it with a selector like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="@color/...." android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="@color/...."/> <!-- disabled -->
</selector>
```

and

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
     app:backgroundTint="@color/selector"
     ../>
```

[image]

You can also apply a theme overlay to override the `colorOnSurface` and use the default selector:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.App.FloatingActionButton"
      ../>
```

with:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.FloatingActionButton" parent="">
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you. In which file should I put the last xml (style name="ThemeOverlay.App.FloatingActionButton" etc.)?

Comment: in styles.xml o themes.xml

Comment: If I put it in `res/values/styles.xml`, I get a compilation error:
Can't determine type for tag '<item name="colorOnSurface">@color/colorGray</item>'
What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know. Do you have issues with the other styles?

Comment: I haven't used any other styles yet, I had to create that file

Comment: @writzlpfrimpft You should have a default themes.xml file. Check in the Manifest.xml what is your default theme.